# How to load a Properties File when the ClassLoader is in the EJB jar and the Properties File is in war

Tags: java, classloader, websphere-7

I have this problem. I want to load a properties file located in a war file but the class loader is in another jar file. But they are compiled in one ear file. When I place the properties file in src folder of the jar file's project, it works but I wanted to put it in Web-INF/Classes for future update purposes.

Details.

Compiled in EAR
EJB
IBM Websphere

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You war depends on your EJB but the EJB does not depends on your war.

Thus, it's not possible.

If configuration must be updated, you should externalize it.
You won't be able to modify files in your war.

A good practice is to generate EJB jars and WARs independtly of the environment.
It will enable your Exploitation team to deploy the same code in every environment. They will just need to adapt the externalized property files (DB login / password, etc...).

Comment: Thank you Sir. That's a great help! Is there any other way? Like ejb.jar accessing the file in app server? Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't access the deployed code. The only way is to load the property from outside the app server.

Comment: add 
    -Dconfig.path=/pat/to/config/files
 to your startup script and then access to the files
    usingSystem.getProperty("config.path").